# How do you draw a string on macOS in overriden draw-function of a custom CALayer subclass?

Tags: swift, string, macos, calayer, cgcontext

Why is the following code not drawing a string in a macOS application?

```
class MyLayer: CALayer {
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        let text = "TEXT"
        let textRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        text.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: [.font: font])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALayer`‘s `draw(in:)` method is built on top of Core Graphics. All Core Graphics drawing functions take a `CGContext` as an argument (or, in Swift, are methods on `CGContext`). That’s why Core Animation passes a `CGContext` to your `draw(in:)` method.

However, the `draw(in:withAttributes:)` method on `String` is not part of Core Graphics. It is part of AppKit. AppKit’s drawing methods don’t operate directly on a `CGContext`. They operate on an `NSGraphicsContext` (which wraps a `CGContext`). But, as you can see from the `draw(in:withAttributes:)` method, AppKit’s drawing functions don’t take an `NSGraphicsContext` argument and aren’t methods on `NSGraphicsContext`.

Instead, there’s a global (per-thread) `NSGraphicsContext`. The AppKit drawing methods use this global context. Since you’re writing code down at the Core Animation level, AppKit didn’t set up a global `NSGraphicsContext` for you. You need to set it up yourself:

```
class MyLayer: CALayer {
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        let nsgc = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: ctx, flipped: false)
        NSGraphicsContext.current = nsgc

        let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        let text = "TEXT"
        let textRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        text.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: [.font: font])
    }
}
```

Comment: What a clear and informative answer! Out of curiosity: doesn't `CGContext` itself have string drawing methods?

Comment: Core Graphics's string-drawing functions were deprecated a few years ago. The documentation tells you to use Core Text instead. If you only need very simple string drawing, using AppKit's methods is probably good enough. If you need more power, look at Text Kit.